# proxy_pass doesn't work in the location area in the NGINX config

Tags: nginx, proxy, location, proxypass

I have this nginx config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
        worker_connections 768;
}
http {
        server {
            listen 443 default_server ssl;  
            ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/privkey.pem;

            location /private/ {
                #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                #index index.html;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5001/;
            }

             location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
            }
        }


        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets on;
        ssl_session_timeout 28h;
        ssl_early_data on;
        ssl_buffer_size 16k;
        http2_chunk_size  8k;
```

Also I have same python servers on my localhost :

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      549524/python3
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      549204/python3
```

The problem is that
proxy_pass in location / always works, and if I turn off python server on 5000 port, nginx will raise me 504 bad gateway.  proxy_pass in the location /private/ doesn't work, and nginx server always raise me 404 not found.

If i turn off my server on 5001 nothing will change. But if i change this area  this way:

```
            location /private/ {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                index index.html;
                #proxy_pass http://localhost:5001/;
            }
```

Everything will work and nginx return me index.html.

Why doesn't work proxy_pass in this location area?

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing the second / from **/private/**:

```
    location /private {
                #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                #index index.html;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5001/;
    }
```